# Pixelated Image on iOS

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, gravatar

I'm using a gravatar image on the site I'm developing like so:

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eb937db173cfc0b05f6821e5f88bd26c?s=25"
     class="gravatar_icon" title="Gravatar Icon"
     style="float: left; margin: 10px 8px 8px;"/>
```

When this image is displayed on iOS it's pixelated. From what I've found so far it looks like this is because of the responsive design. I was wondering if there was a way for me to use a specific `img` tag for mobile and one for desktop.

Comment: There is not much details about whole layout but I assume its cause by highres screen of iOS devices. Try using higher resolution image with image width and size.

<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eb937db173cfc0b05f6821e5f88bd26c?s=50"
     class="gravatar_icon" title="Gravatar Icon"
     style="float: left; margin: 10px 8px 8px;width:25px; height:25px"/>

Comment: @DamianKrawczyk That does the trick. If you write this up as an answer I'll give you credit. :)